# Adding an attribute to a Python dictionary from the standard library

Tags: python, dictionary, attributes

I was wondering if you could add an attribute to a Python dictionary?

```
class myclass():
    def __init__(): 
     self.mydict = {}  # initialize a regular dict
     self.mydict.newattribute = "A description of what this dictionary will hold"
     >>> AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'newattribute'
     setattr(self.mydict, "attribute", "A description of what this dictionary will hold"
     >>> AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'newattribute'
```

Is there anyway to quickly add my description attribute without having to copy the dict class and overloading the constructor. I thought it would be simple, but I guess I was wrong.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Just derive from `dict`:

```
class MyDict(dict):
    pass
```

Instances of `MyDict` behave like a `dict`, but can have custom attributes:

```
>>> d = MyDict()
>>> d.my_attr = "whatever"
>>> d.my_attr
'whatever'
```

Answer (score 4):

If you feel like creating your own class would be overkill, you can also drop-in replace the dict with a `collections.UserDict`.

Untested example:

```
from collections import UserDict

d = UserDict({"foo": "bar"})
d.description = "my dict with attributes"
d["baz"] = 42
```

For reference:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.UserDict