# Is there a way to set a value and an attribute of an object simultaneously?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Question [Adding an attribute to a python dictionary from the standard library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11532060/adding-an-attribute-to-a-python-dictionary-from-the-standard-library) shows how to add an attribute to a built-in datatype. But is there a way to add an attribute to a variable in one step so that it can be used in a function call, equivalent to the following:

```
>>> class Adict(dict):
        pass

>>> def myfunc(x):
        print(x, x.my_attr)

>>> v = {'a':'cat'}
>>> var = Adict(v)
>>> var.my_attr = 'whatever'
>>> myfunc(var)
{'a': 'cat'} whatever
```

I want to reduce the last 3 lines to a single line, something like:

```
>>> myfunc(Adict(v, my_attr='whatever'))
```

which passes a dictionary with two items ('a' and 'my_attr') and no attributes, or

```
>>> myfunc(Adict(v).my_attr='whatever')
```

which is parsed as a keyword parameter instead of an attribute setting. Is there a way to set a value and an attribute in a single step?

-------- EDIT ----------

To answer Sven's question, I am working on extending the excellent [genson](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/genson/0.1.0) JSON schema processor, which includes the following code:

```
    # parse properties and add them individually
    for prop, val in schema.items():
        if prop == 'type':
            self._add_type(val)
        elif prop == 'required':
            self._add_required(val)
        elif prop in ['properties', 'patternProperties']:
            v = Adict(val)
            v._ptype = prop
            self._add_properties(v, 'add_schema')
        elif prop == 'items':
            self._add_items(val, 'add_schema')
        elif prop not in self._other:
            self._other[prop] = val
```

I don't need anything special with the custom dict except to be able to tag it with an attribute, and it would be nice to be able to clean up my butt-ugly 3 lines of code under `properties` so that it visually matches the other cases :-).  What I'll likely do instead is pass that tag separately to the `self._add_properties()` function.

Comment: Let's restart. This line `{'a': 'cat'} whatever`  is throwing me off. Can you explain what that is exactly?

Comment: Adding that information as a property to the value is a rather uncommon approach. Using a separate parameter seems much better, or maybe even a separate function.  (The two functions can call a common helper function under the hood.)

Comment: The `genson` data structures are nested to arbitrary depth and processed recursively.  I needed a way to handle, e.g., a dict of dicts of lists of dicts while keeping track of the type (independent or merged) of each.  An attribute (as in getattr()) seemed like the most straightforward way to stamp a type on each dict, even if it is uncommon.  In JSON terminology "properties" are the keys/values of a dict, so attaching a tag to the dict without adding a key/value is the goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may introduce what is called a builder (or a class factory pattern) that gets all the neccessary arguments and returns the resulting object. Is this what you want?

```
class Adict(dict):
    pass

def myfunc(x):
    print(x, x.my_attr)

def my_builder(v, **kvargs):
    obj = Adict(v)
    obj.__dict__.update(kvargs)  # internal dictionary with attributes
    return obj                   # return the created object

# Your original code.    
v = {'a':'cat'}
var = Adict(v)
var.my_attr = 'whatever'
myfunc(var)

print('------------')

v2 = {'d': 'dog'}
myfunc(my_builder(v2, my_attr='whatever_dog'))

print('------------')

myfunc(my_builder({'c': 'crocodile'}, my_attr='whatever_croc'))
```

This is rather straightforward way to do exactly what you did on the three lines. However, the builder may be later much smarter. It can test the values and types of the arguments, and based on the situation, object of other types can be created, initialized, and returned as a result. This is what the *class factory* pattern was designed for -- the agent that does the work for you. (Here the problem is that you are throwing the `obj` away after `myfunc()` is executed, but you probably mean to do something else with the object -- pass it somewhere or whatever.)

Comment: Great!  Always good to learn a new design pattern.  Now all I need to do is study up on the magic `obj.__dict__.update()` incantation.

Comment: The `__dict__` attribute is the internal dictionary of each object. It keeps all attributes that belong to the object and that are not fixed somehow with respect to the basic functionality of the class/object. It means that any variable or method name is stored here, and the value is the value part of that dictionary item. The `.update()` is a dictionary methods that updates the dictionary with the content of the argument dictionary. The `**kvargs` is a dictionary built of the key/value arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the constructor of `Adict` to accept a keyword argument and set an attribute based on it:

```
class Adict(dict):
    def __init__(*args, my_attr=None, **kwargs):
        self = args[0]
        self.my_attr = my_attr
        dict.__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

This gives you a dictionary that is altered in a somewhat weird way, since the `my_attr` keyword argument will behave differently than all other keyword arguments.  (You could also choose not to pass `kwargs` on to the `dict` constructor.)

Comment: Thanks, but if there isn't a Pythonic 'non-wierd' syntax to do that, I'll just have to put the extra lines in the program.  It's more readable with three lines, but I was hoping there was a compact idiom.

Comment: @Dave Adding a custom attribute to a dictionary is something rather uncommon to do.  If you need something like that, you usually want to use a custom class anyway, not a built-in dictionary, so writing a custom constructor would be the way to go.  The only reason this becomes weird is that I tried to keep the custom class as compatible with the built-in dict as possible.  Maybe you could give a bit more context on what you are trying to achieve.